# How can I copy all cells with "!" in formula and paste values on top of them?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm an absolute zero beginner in VBA, and the only thing I know is what I intend to do is not possible via available features in Excel and needs a VBA code. So if anyone is willing to kindly help, I would need a complete VBA code ready to run! Thanks.

Task: In a very large sheet, I need to copy all cells (scattered around) containing "!" in their formula (i.e. all cells that refer to other sheets), and replace them with their respective values (similar to 'paste values'). The aim of this task is to eliminate all references to other worksheets to achieve a completely standalone sheet, while keeping all values intact.

So I guess what I need is a loop which goes through the whole sheet, copies a cell if it has an exclamation mark in its formula, and pastes the value in the exact same place. The loop should cover the whole sheet.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
        If InStr(r.Formula, "!") > 0 Then r.Value = r.Value
    Next r
End Sub
```

---

- Declare an object variable to hold a reference to the cells you're going to be iterating.

  ```
  Dim r As Range
  ```
- Acquire all cells in the active sheet that have a formula

  ```
  ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
  ```
- Loop through all acquired cells; each cell is a `Range` object spanning 1 row and 1 column, so you use your `r` object variable as your "iteration variable", and a `For Each` loop construct to iterate all individual cells:

  ```
  For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
  ```

  You could also have extracted an object variable to hold the cells you're going to be iterating:

  ```
  Dim cellsWithFormula As Range
  Set cellsWithFormula = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlFormulas)

  For Each r In cellsWithFormula
  ```
- You can access a cell's formula using its `Formula` property, and use the built-in `InStr` function to verify whether it contains an  exclamation mark:

  ```
  If InStr(r.Formula, "!") > 0 Then
  ```

  `InStr` returns the start index of the string you're looking for, if it was found; if it wasn't found, it returns 0 - so we know a formula contains an exclamation mark if the return value is greater than 0. If the formula contains an exclamation mark at the 20th character, the function will return 20.
- To replace the formula with its value, you simply assign it its `Value`

  ```
  r.Value = r.Value
  ```

  This eliminates the formula and replaces it with whatever it was last evaluated to. Note that if the worksheet isn't calculated due to `Application.Calculation` being set to `xlCalculationManual`, this means doing that will write the wrong value. You can force a recalculation of an individual cell by calling its `Calculate` method *before* you overwrite the formula, like this:

  ```
  r.Calculate
  ```

Comment: I've edited your answer to include more "fishing rod", hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Mat'sMug  I think your edit is excellent! Thank you for taking the time to add this valuable tutorial material.